# Determine an inner product space.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

I am given that V is a vector space $M_{3,3}(\Bbb R)$  and that function $\langle A,B\rangle\,=\,tr(A^T\cdot B)$ prove this function is an inner product.

So far I have taken these steps:

From the function  = $tr( A^T \cdot B)$. Allowing A and B to be 3*3 square matrices. Then it follows we would get , $(a_{11}, a_{22}, a_{33}), (b_{11},b_{22},b_{33})$.  Next we would need to prove that it is an inner product using the four axioms:

1. For the first axiom we can prove this by writing $\langle A^T,B\rangle = A_1{_1} B_1{_1} + A_2{_2} B_2{_2} + A_3{_3} B_3{_3}$, Which by the commutative property of addition can be rewritten as  $\langle B, A^T\rangle$.
2. For the second axiom we can prove this by the distributive property of addition in much the same way as the first axiom.
3. I am getting a little confused on this third axiom it states that $\ c\,\langle U,V\rangle = \langle c\,U,V\rangle$. The $c$ is just a scalar that would be distributed to both vectors so how could $c$ only be applied to one vector.
4. Finally since any  $M_{3,3}(\Bbb R)$ includes matrices with negative numbers and is odd the trace will be negative therefore $\langle V,V\rangle \lt 0$, so I would have to conclude that this is not a inner product.

Comment: Your first formulae $\langle A^T,B \rangle = A_{1,1} B_{1,1} + A_{2,2} B_{2,2} +A_{3,3} B_{3,3}$ is not correct. Can you write compute the product of the matrices $A^T B$.

Comment: Those are not axioms, you're just verifying whether the definitions are true or not for that function.
Moreover, in the third one: the scalar **does not** distribute to both vectors. Check out again the properties of the linear functions.